# Prevent Django model field from being rendered

Tags: django, django-models

I'm adding a per-user secret key to one of my Django models for internal usage, but I want to make sure that it is not accidentally exposed to the user. Obviously, I can check all the forms using that model today and ensure that they exclude the field, but that is not future proof. **Is there any way I can mark a field so it is never rendered or sent to the client even if a form otherwise includes it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `editable=False` on your Model field as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.editable) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use)

> If False, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other
> ModelForm. They are also skipped during model validation. Default is
> True.

Note this works for `ModelForms` and if you are using regular `Form` you might consider extending  it with custom implementation

---

ModelForm editable removal implementation [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3f7b3275627385f8f7531fca01cdda50d4ec6b6e/django/forms/models.py#L32)